# Not Showing dialoag when there is no internet

Tags: android

Hi in the below code After clicking login button with internet working fine.suppose there is no internet connection it's not working I want to show diaglog there is no internet connection.

Can any one help me from this issue.

**Login1.java**

```
public class Login1 extends Activity {  

    protected static final int NOT_CONNECTED_TO_SERVICE = 0;
    protected static final int FILL_BOTH_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD = 1;
    public static final String AUTHENTICATION_FAILED = "0";
    public static final String FRIEND_LIST = "FRIEND_LIST";
    protected static final int MAKE_SURE_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_CORRECT = 2 ;
    protected static final int NOT_CONNECTED_TO_NETWORK = 3;
    private EditText usernameText;
    private EditText passwordText;
    private Button cancelButton;
    private IAppManager imService;
    public static final int SIGN_UP_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    public static final int EXIT_APP_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;


    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

            imService = ((IMService.IMBinder)service).getService();  

            if (imService.isUserAuthenticated() == true)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Login1.this, FriendList.class);                                                               
                startActivity(i);
                Login1.this.finish();
            }
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {

            imService = null;
            Toast.makeText(Login1.this, R.string.local_service_stopped,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    


        startService(new Intent(Login1.this,  IMService.class));            


        setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);
        setTitle("Login");

        Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_login);
        usernameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);        

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                 new LoadViewTask().execute(); 



                   isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                   if (!isInternetPresent) {
                       showAlertDialog(Login1.this, "No Internet Connection",
                               "You don't have internet connection.", true);

                       return;


                   }
                if (imService == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.not_connected_to_service, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    return;
                }
                else if (imService.isNetworkConnected() == false)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.not_connected_to_network, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    showDialog(NOT_CONNECTED_TO_NETWORK);

                }
                else if (usernameText.length() > 0 && 
                    passwordText.length() > 0)
                {

                    Thread loginThread = new Thread(){
                        private Handler handler = new Handler();
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            String result = null;
                            try {
                                result = imService.authenticateUser(usernameText.getText().toString(), passwordText.getText().toString());
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if (result == null || result.equals(AUTHENTICATION_FAILED)) 
                            {

                                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                                    public void run() { 
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.make_sure_username_and_password_correct, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                    }                                   
                                });

                            }
                            else {


                                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                                    public void run() {                                     
                                        Intent i = new Intent(Login1.this, FriendList.class);                                               

                                        startActivity(i);   
                                        Login1.this.finish();
                                    }                                   
                                });

                            }

                        }
                    };
                    loginThread.start();

                }
                else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.fill_both_username_and_password, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }               
            }           
        });

        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {                   
                imService.exit();
                finish();

            }

        });


    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
    {       
        int message = -1;       
        switch (id) 
        {
            case NOT_CONNECTED_TO_SERVICE:
                message = R.string.not_connected_to_service;            
                break;
            case FILL_BOTH_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD:
                message = R.string.fill_both_username_and_password;
                break;
            case MAKE_SURE_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_CORRECT:
                message = R.string.make_sure_username_and_password_correct;
                break;
            case NOT_CONNECTED_TO_NETWORK:
                message = R.string.not_connected_to_network;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (message == -1) 
        {
            return null;
        }
        else 
        {
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(Login1.this)       
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            })        
            .create();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {       
        bindService(new Intent(Login1.this, IMService.class), mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
        boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

         menu.add(0, SIGN_UP_ID, 0, R.string.sign_up);
         menu.add(0, EXIT_APP_ID, 0, R.string.exit_application);


        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()) 
        {
            case SIGN_UP_ID:
                Intent i = new Intent(Login1.this, SignUp.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            case EXIT_APP_ID:
                cancelButton.performClick();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();


        alertDialog.setTitle(title);


        alertDialog.setMessage(message);


        alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);


        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });


        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>  
    {  
        //Before running code in separate thread  
        @Override  
        protected void onPreExecute()  
        {  
             progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login1.this,"Loading...",  
                    "Loading application View, please wait...", false, false);  
          progressDialog.show(); 
        }  


        @Override  
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)  
        {  

            try  
            {  

                synchronized (this)  
                {  

                    int counter = 0;  

                    while(counter <= 4)  
                    {  

                        this.wait(850);  

                        counter++;  

                        publishProgress(counter*25);  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
            catch (InterruptedException e)  
            {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
            return null;  
        }  


        @Override  
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)  
        {  

            progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);  
        }  

        @Override  
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)  
        {  

            progressDialog.dismiss();  


        }  

    }
```

Comment: That is a LOT of code, could you try and trim it down to a simple, complete example of what you're after? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details about what makes a good example.

Comment: In my code where I did wrong

Comment: I don't know and with the huge amount of code I'm not going to spend ages trying to find out. I'm also fairly certain that other users of this site won't either so I'd REALLY recommend trying to narrow your code down a minimal example required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: debug whether the isInternetPresent returns true value or not.I suspect it is always returning true!

Comment: it's not calling  isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you said :

> I want to show diaglog there is no internet connection.

Use this function :

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
      ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)  getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
```

and in your code check internet connection :

```
if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
    // show your dialog here 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this function

```
public static boolean CheckInternet(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        return wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected();
    }
```

This function check the wifi or the mobile network if available and return true if yes false if no

and replace this:

```
if (!isInternetPresent) {
        showAlertDialog(Login1.this, "No Internet Connection",
        "You don't have internet connection.", true);
return;
}
```

By this code:

```
if (!CheckInternet(this)) {
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
 alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
 alertDialog.setMessage("Internet not available, Cross check your internet connectivity and try again");
alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     finish();
   }
});

alertDialog.show();
  return;
                   }
```

Comment: replace the isInternetPresent() method by this CheckIntenert(Context context) with context argument, it worked well to me